# Does Crypto.generateMac method work exactly the same as Mac and SecretKeySpec java classes

Tags: apex, java, crypto

I need to create a signature in order to send a request to CyberSource. I have the following Java code, that works perfectly:

```
String signatureString = "Test";

final Mac sha256HMAC = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
final SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(

Base64.getDecoder().decode("LZjfTQi8uxEn5VFI3S4Ml+8UY4y3b2F0aP8c8WuiQtY="), "HmacSHA256");
sha256HMAC.init(secretKey);
sha256HMAC.update(signatureString.toString().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
final byte[] hashBytes = sha256HMAC.doFinal();
final String signatureB64 = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(hashBytes);
System.out.println(signatureB64.toString()); //nbXkkkM3GuPp8YEIb7JnAj4IrDy0YC7t3Pl/cJxStW0=
```

I tried to make the same on Apex, but it shows me different result:

```
String signatureString = 'Test';
System.debug(generateHmacSHA256Signature(signatureString, 'LZjfTQi8uxEn5VFI3S4Ml+8UY4y3b2F0aP8c8WuiQtY=')); //5zJnHFYz6HklMZ8vR4rf7UJfjrumiexZeYDgsuErrk=

public static String generateHmacSHA256Signature(String input, String secretKey) {
    String algorithmName = 'HmacSHA256';
    Blob mac = Crypto.generateMac(algorithmName, Blob.valueOf(input), Blob.valueOf(Secretkey));
    String macUrl = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(mac);
    return macUrl;
}
```

So Java returns `nbXkkkM3GuPp8YEIb7JnAj4IrDy0YC7t3Pl/cJxStW0=` and Apex `5zJnHFYz6HklMZ8vR4rf7UJfjrumiexZeYDgsuErrk=` results are different.

How can I get the same result, as in Java? Any help very appriciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your Apex code just misses the base64 decoding step on your secret key. If you change the call to `generateMac()` to this:

```
Blob mac = Crypto.generateMac(algorithmName, Blob.valueOf(input), EncodingUtil.base64Decode(Secretkey));
```

You'll get back

> 10:39:43:003 USER_DEBUG [2]|DEBUG|nbXkkkM3GuPp8YEIb7JnAj4IrDy0YC7t3Pl/cJxStW0=

Comment: I wasted almost all day to try different combinations of `EncodingUtil.base64Decode` and `Blob.valueOf`, but on more complicated input... What's a fresh view mean!